# How can I have a global object that is thread-safe in a Flask application?

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to build a REST API with `Flask` that's supposed to respond based on a statistical model implemented with `pandas` and `numpy`.  The model is a constant for a set number of days, after which it needs to be updated (reloaded from an object store).  My response time needs to be fast, so I thought I can just hold it in memory and do my calculations as needed before responding.  While that works standalone, I can't seem to find a way to use this simple architecture in a `Flask` application.

I have explored using `session` with `session.permanent` set to `True`, but that requires my [model to be serialisable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42937612). That is non-trivial for my case. I also don't know how to handle `permanent_session_lifetime` if I take this approach.  I presume, I would need to reset this timer? How do I achieve that? Is it as simple as creating a new `secret_key`?

I also considered using `app.config`, but there I'm not sure how a model update would be handled in a multi-threaded environment (in production).